# Custom function not showing JQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-plugins, prettyphoto

I'm a newbie in Jquery. I'm trying to print text on a document dynamically. I have a JavaScript function that is supposed to display images using the jQuery prettyphoto plugin. My function does not show the images but when I paste the code on a html file it works fine. Please help. A sample of my code is here.

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./index.css" type="text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="spin.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="custom-functions.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./prettyPhoto/css/prettyPhoto.css" type="text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./prettyPhoto/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
    $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto_related-content-images']").prettyPhoto({theme:'facebook'});
    });

 function showImages()
    {
    var stringData = '';

    stringData = stringData + '<div id="related-content-images" >Related to this: <br/>'+
    '<a href="images/sample-album-2.jpg" target="" rel="prettyPhoto_related-content-images[related-content-images]" title=""><img id="not-hidden" src="images/sample-album-2.jpg" alt="" title=""></a>'+
    '<a href="images/sample-album-3.jpg" target="" rel="prettyPhoto_related-content-images[related-content-images]" title=""><img id="related-images" src="images/sample-album-3.jpg" alt="" title=""></a>'+
    '<a href="images/sample-album-4.jpg" target="" rel="prettyPhoto_related-content-images[related-content-images]" title=""><img id="related-images" src="images/sample-album-4.jpg" alt="" title=""></a></div>';
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML=''+stringData+'';
    }
    </script>

    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="header"><div id="app-logo-image">
    <img src="images/app-logo.png" id="app-logo"/></div>
    <div id="header-form">
    <input type="search" id="search-text-box" name="search-text-box" placeholder="Search">
    <input type="submit" id="search-button" name="" value="Search">
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="container">
    <div id="sub-header-menu">
    <div id="music-albums">
    <img src="images/music-albums-icon.png" id="music-albums-image"; onclick="fetch('music-albums');"/></div>
    <div id="genres-icon">
    <img src="images/genres-icon.png" id="genres-icon-image"onclick="fetch('music-genres');"/></div>
    <div id="artist-icon">
    <img src="images/artists-icon.png" id="artist-icon-image"onclick="fetch('music-artists');"/></div>
    <div id="home-icon">
    <img src="images/home-button.png" id="home-icon-image"/></div>
    </div>
    <div id="content" style="left:0%;">
    <a href="#" onclick="showImages();">click me</a>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Please include the code where you call `prettyPhoto`

Comment: @georgebrock I've added the whole script

Comment: Possible answer located here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5674440/how-to-open-a-file-with-print-dialogue-box-using-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `showImages` function isn't executed until the link is clicked, however the `prettyPhoto` initialisation is only run once when the document finishes loading, and since `showImages` hasn't been run yet `prettyPhotos` can't find and enhance those images.

If you add this to the end of `showImages` everything should work:

```
$('#content a').prettyPhoto({theme:'facebook'});
```

Comment: Where exactly did you add the new call to `prettyPhoto`?

Comment: The function showImages() dynamically prints a div that you click on to display images.

Comment: Yes, it does dynamically create a `div`. After the `div` has been created, you need to call `prettyPhoto`.