# Print PDF in a Popup with Javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf

I would like to print a PDF in an Popup window in Firefox 30 with Javascript.

When I looked at on firebug, I received this message "**Error: Permission denied to access property 'print'**"

Is there a workaround ?

Here my simple code :

> var myWin = open("my-pdf.pdf");
>   frames["myWin"].focus();
>   frames["myWin"].print();

Comment: If you want to print a window, you have to do `window.print()`

Comment: Duplicate? "How to open a file with print dialogue box using JavaScript" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5674440/how-to-open-a-file-with-print-dialogue-box-using-javascript

Comment: OP, where do you get the frames var from?

Comment: Also, a quick search found me this: [How to open print dialog box to print page or part of the page in JavaScript](http://www.dotnetbull.com/2011/08/openig-print-dialog-box-through.html)

Comment: Just do `myWin.print()`. `frames` is not correct here.

Comment: frames is an array of objects on Firefox. But if we try with : myWin.print(), we have always the error : "Permission denied...". Why ?

Comment: Not a duplicate because this question is specific to PDF printing. I suspect that JavaScript cannot do this (at least not reliably), but there might indeed be a way. I've seen it done in Google Docs.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this bug; Updating compatability.js and this started working for me.